# Dynamically add google maps div into DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-maps-api-3

I'm wanting to add the Google Maps API div, `<div id="map"></div>` within a card that's dynamically added to the DOM, after a user has input a search. I'm able to append it the main div, as a test, but not within the card one I'm appending after the the card is inserted into the DOM.

Code is below.

```js
const APIURL = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/'
const GOOGLE_MAPS_API = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDhlU1KMTlTh4C__bTJBxbVA-s7wvQbO9E&callback=initMap'
const main = document.getElementById('main')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const search = document.getElementById('search')

async function getCountryData(name) {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(APIURL + name)

        data.forEach(res => {
            const countryData = res

            addGMapsEl()
            createCountryCard(countryData)
            getLatLngPos(countryData)
        } )
        } catch (err) {
        if(err.response.status == 404) {
            createErrorCard('No countries found')
            setTimeout(() => { 
                main.innerHTML = ''}
                , 1500);
        }
    }
}

// Google Map API 
function addGMapsEl() {
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = GOOGLE_MAPS_API;
script.defer = true;

document.head.appendChild(script);

const mapDiv = document.createElement('div')

      mapDiv.id = 'map'
      main.appendChild(mapDiv)
}

let map;

function initMap() {
  
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 51, lng: 9},
    zoom: 7
  });
}

function createCountryCard(country) {
    const cardHTML = `
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="card">
         <div class="wrapper">
             <div class="card-title">
              <h2>${country.name}</h2>
              <h4>Capital: ${country.capital}</h4>
              <h5>Population: ${country.population.toLocaleString('en')}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-image">
          <img
            src="${country.flag}"
            alt="${country.name +'-flag'}"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="map-content">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <ul class="card-list">
            <li><strong>Region:</strong> ${country.region}</li>
            <li><strong>Subregion:</strong> ${country.subregion}</li>
            <li><strong>Currency:</strong> ${country.currencies[0].name}<span> ${country.currencies[0].symbol}</span></li>
            <li><strong>Spoken Language:</strong> ${country.languages[0].name}</li>
            <li><strong>Timezone:</strong> ${country.timezones}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
  main.innerHTML += cardHTML
}

// Creates error card after no results found
function createErrorCard(msg) {
    const cardHTML = `
    <div class="card">
        <h1>${msg}</h1>
    </div>
    `
    main.innerHTML = cardHTML
}

// Clears the DOM on search 
function clearDOM() {
  main.innerHTML = ''
}



// Search Input
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
 
    clearDOM()

    const countryName = search.value
    if(countryName) {
        getCountryData(countryName)

        search.value = ''
    }
})
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="search-container">
          <form id="form" class="form">
            <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for country..." />
          </form>
        </div>
        <main id="main"></main>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
      </body>
```

Comment: Hi Matt - you need to add all the code you have into the snippet or at least put there enough to make it running. There is nothing that works by now. The function `createCountryCard` is never used. Map init fuction creates map on element with id `map`. If you want to make map in your custom element just give it some different id and when your element exist in the DOM init the map with your custom ID of your element.

Comment: sorry, I though it had pasted it all in. I'll add it now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - so - to create a MAP you need to use `new google.maps.Map( ELEMENT_TO_CONTAIN_THE_MAP, MAP_OPTIONS)` which is in your `mapInit` func.
You should also load the API only once - so i moved things a little bit in your code...

I have removed the `callback=initMap` from your maps url - because your element doesn't exist in the DOM at the moment when google's script is loaded.
Then placed the call to `mapInit` after your `createCountryCard` call - because it adds your map element to the DOM - and now we can place the map within it.

Given your element the id argument `<div class="map-content" id="map-content">`. And then changed the id in `mapInit` function to match your elements id which is `map-content`.

```js
const APIURL = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/'
const GOOGLE_MAPS_API = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDhlU1KMTlTh4C__bTJBxbVA-s7wvQbO9E'
const main = document.getElementById('main')
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const search = document.getElementById('search')

async function getCountryData(name) {
  try {
    const {
      data
    } = await axios.get(APIURL + name)

    data.forEach(res => {
      const countryData = res

      //gmaps element is on card
      createCountryCard(countryData);
      initMap();
      getLatLngPos(countryData)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response.status == 404) {
      createErrorCard('No countries found')
      setTimeout(() => {
        main.innerHTML = ''
      }, 1500);
    }
  }
}

// Google Map API 
function addGMapsEl() {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = GOOGLE_MAPS_API;
  script.defer = true;

  document.head.appendChild(script);
  const mapDiv = document.createElement('div')

  mapDiv.id = 'map'
  main.appendChild(mapDiv)
}

let map;

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-content"), {
    center: {
      lat: 51,
      lng: 9
    },
    zoom: 7
  });
}

function createCountryCard(country) {
  const cardHTML = `
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="card">
         <div class="wrapper">
             <div class="card-title">
              <h2>${country.name}</h2>
              <h4>Capital: ${country.capital}</h4>
              <h5>Population: ${country.population.toLocaleString('en')}</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-image">
          <img
            src="${country.flag}"
            alt="${country.name +'-flag'}"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="map-content" class="map-content">
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <ul class="card-list">
            <li><strong>Region:</strong> ${country.region}</li>
            <li><strong>Subregion:</strong> ${country.subregion}</li>
            <li><strong>Currency:</strong> ${country.currencies[0].name}<span> ${country.currencies[0].symbol}</span></li>
            <li><strong>Spoken Language:</strong> ${country.languages[0].name}</li>
            <li><strong>Timezone:</strong> ${country.timezones}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
  main.innerHTML += cardHTML
}

// Creates error card after no results found
function createErrorCard(msg) {
  const cardHTML = `
    <div class="card">
        <h1>${msg}</h1>
    </div>
    `
  main.innerHTML = cardHTML
}

// Clears the DOM on search 
function clearDOM() {
  main.innerHTML = ''
}



// Search Input
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  clearDOM()

  const countryName = search.value
  if (countryName) {
    getCountryData(countryName)

    search.value = ''
  }
})

addGMapsEl();
```

```css
.map-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.card-image img {
    max-height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #aaa;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form id="form" class="form">
      <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for country..." />
    </form>
  </div>
  <main id="main"></main>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Looks like it works now ...you probably want to use `setCenter` on yor map later to move the view to the new location - do it after `mapInit`

Added some CSS also - to give a size for the map element and shrink that huge flag you had.

Comment: that works great, thank you! now I just need to figure out how to pass in the long and lat values form the API into the map, for each search request. ha!

Comment: @MattDavis just put `map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(...countryData.latlng));` under `mapInit()` call... 
P.S.: You also should read the reference - there is much more you can do. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral

Answer (score 0):

I can see the url in your constant is wrong ...  the correct one will be :

```
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap'
```

Another thing you never call `addGMapsEl()` function to initialize the map.

Finally the `.card-content` element isn't presented on DOM.

To present the country on map you should create an event to handle that

```
$(document).on("input", "#search", function(e){
   //handle input information here
})
```

Comment: I missed some of the JS out of the snippet, I've corrected it now. I can append to the main div, but I want to append within the <div class="map-content"></div> after the card is inserted into the DOM.